# Existe algun algoritmo para evitar perder información en una diferencia x(i)-x(i-1)?

Tags: python, algoritmos, function, math

Tengo una variable x=x(i). Definimos otra variable dx tal que:

`$$dx(i)=x(i)-x(i-1)$$`

Aquí estamos perdiendo un valor (llamémosle  `dx(0)`).

De nuevo, definamos otra variable dx_=dx_(i) tal que:

`$$dx_(i)=\frac{dx(i)-dx(i-1)}{dx(i-1)}$$`

Aquí, ahora estamos perdiendo otro punto (`dx_(1)` por culpa de `dx(0)` (ya que este no existe). Además, `dx_(0)` tampoco está definido. Existe alguna forma de evitar esto?

La cosa es que no puedo pre-definir unas "condiciones de contorno" para estos valores.

La variable `x` son los casos acumulados de personas por COVID. Digamos que el índice `i` son los días.

La variable `dx` son los casos nuevos diarios acumulados de COVID  (entre `i` e `i-1`) .

La variable `dx_` es la variable anteriormente definida. Estamos usando redes para predecir el comportamiento de estas variables. Si le damos ciertos valores iniciales a estas variables de contorno, la red se vuelve completamente inestable, pues si ponemos a `0` los casos acumulados (ignorando ya el problema que puede dar un denominador) y al día siguiente aparecen 50 nuevos casos, la red de predicción no es capaz de lidiar con semejante cambio para dar un valor coherente.

No se si me he expicado correctamente y si la categoría donde cae esta pregunta es aquí.
Un saludo

Comment: Pero se supone que `i=0` corresponde al inicio de la epidemia ... hoy ya estamos como en `i=200`

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo muy bien la pregunta debido a que no hay datos de ejemplo ni el resultado esperado. A lo que entiendo yo haría algo así:

```py
casos_por_dia = [3, 9, 6, 5, 10, 4, 2, 6, 3, 0]

def x(i):
    if (i == 0):
        return 0
    else:
        return casos_por_dia[i-1]

def dx(i):
    return x(i) - x(i-1)

def dx_(i):
    return (dx(i)-dx(i-1))/dx(i-1)
```

Suponiendo que los casos nuevos por día se encuentran en una lista.
Si estoy equivocado no dudes en indicarme para ayudarte con otra respuesta mas acertada.

Saludos!